# Show GitHub commits in a Slack channel

Tags: github, integration, slack

How can I get [GitHub](https://github.com) commits to get posted to a [Slack](https://slack.com) channel?

All I could find in Slack's Help is [this page, "Using the GitHub app with GitHub Enterprise"](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201710957-How-do-I-use-the-GitHub-integration-with-GitHub-Enterprise-) which is only for GitHub Enterprise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Click on the arrow at the upper left of the screen.
2. Click `Configure Integrations`
3. Click on `Github`
4. Choose the channel you want news to be posted to
5. Authentify
6. Select the repository and branch to get news from
7. Select the type of news you want
8. Click `Save integration`

Comment: I'll add to this that you can only monitor your own repositories, not ones you're allowed to view (private ones, shared with you)

so for this, probably you have to get the owner to do the integration for you

Answer (score 3):

If you're also wanting to get notified on repositories which are not your own (e.g. we use this for new commits to master on Docker containers we use) then you can grab the RSS feed link from the master branch - go to the GH repo, master branch, view source, search for 'atom', copy link).

Add this to the RSS feed Slack app et voila, notification whenever there's a push to master.

Answer (score 2):

Another option that might be useful to you is Zapier's [Github-Slack](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/slack/) integration: You can push new commits, issues, branches, and other events to Slack as a DM or channel message, or send your Github data to any other supported app.

Disclosure: I work for Zapier

Answer (score -1):

Here's the URL structure to get the commits from `master`:

https://github.com/facebook/react/commits/master.atom